# KineticJS-saveImagedata() , Problems updating to new kineticjs library

Tags: image, html5-canvas, detection, kineticjs

I used kinetic-v3.10.4.js for almost all my work.

Now the requirement changed and I need to add few more functionality that are available in newer versions.

So I started using kinetic-v4.0.1.js.

I made a sample file and it is working fine but few functions like saveImageData();,DetectionType.etc. are not working in 4.0.1 as they have been updated and instead of saveImageData(), createBufferImage() is the new function.

I am redoing everything with kinetic v4.0.1 now.

I can't find the old example in the website that was using createBufferImage() for image event detection as it has been updated to 4.3.3

So anyone having any old example that help in pixel detection/image detection  with 4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about searching from archived internet contents, archive.org

http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://html5canvastutorials.com